# why I'm getting a square instead of a circle in pygame?

Tags: python, pygame

I'm somewhat new to `pygame`. I'm trying to draw a circle, but for some reason I'm getting a square. My code is below. I'd appreciate any help clarifying the issue.

```
import sys, pygame
import random

pygame.init()

SCREEN_SIZE = SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT = 800, 600
BACKGROUND_COLOR = pygame.Color("white")
SCREEN_COLOR = BACKGROUND_COLOR

SCREEN = pygame.display.set_mode(SCREEN_SIZE)

class Splatter:
  def __init__(self, (x, y), r, color):
    self.x = x
    self.y = y
    self.r = r
    self.color = color
    self.surface = pygame.Surface((r*2, r*2))
    self.surface.set_alpha(192)
    self.rect = self.surface.get_rect()

  def display(self):
    self.rect.centerx = self.x
    self.rect.centery = self.y
    pygame.draw.circle(self.surface, self.color, (self.x, self.y), self.r)
    SCREEN.blit(self.surface, self.rect)

def main():
  SCREEN.fill(SCREEN_COLOR)

  s = Splatter((SCREEN.get_width()/2, SCREEN.get_height()/2), 10, pygame.Color("black"))
  s.display()
  pygame.display.flip()
  while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
      if event.type == pygame.QUIT: sys.exit()

if '__main__' == __name__:
  main()
```

**EDIT**

Given the comments and the answer I've changed the code. However I'm still getting a square instead of a circle. My ultimate goal is to have a circle drawn on a surface. So instead of drawing a circle each time, I could simply move the surface on the screen.

```
import sys, pygame
import random

pygame.init()

SCREEN_SIZE = SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT = 800, 600
SCREEN_COLOR = pygame.Color("white")

SCREEN = pygame.display.set_mode(SCREEN_SIZE)

class Splatter(object):
  def __init__(self, (x, y), r):
    self.x = x
    self.y = y
    self.r = r
    self.surface = pygame.Surface((r*2, r*2))
    self.surface.fill(pygame.Color("red"))
    self.rect = self.surface.get_rect()
    pygame.draw.circle(self.surface, pygame.Color("black"), (self.x, self.y), self.r)

  def display(self):
    self.rect.centerx = self.x
    self.rect.centery = self.y
    SCREEN.blit(self.surface, self.rect)


  SCREEN.fill(SCREEN_COLOR)
  s = Splatter((SCREEN.get_width()/2, SCREEN.get_height()/2), 20)
  s.display()

  pygame.display.flip()

  while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
      if event.type == pygame.QUIT: sys.exit()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're painting black circle on black `Surface` and then you put the whole `Surface` on the `SCREEN`. The black circle is there but you obviously don't see it.

Try this (tested).

```
global SCREEN
pygame.draw.circle(SCREEN, self.color, (self.x, self.y), self.r)
pygame.display.flip()
```

As a side note IMHO a lot of your code is useless. You're overthinking this. For example:

```
SCREEN_SIZE = SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT = 800, 600
BACKGROUND_COLOR = pygame.Color("white")
SCREEN_COLOR = BACKGROUND_COLOR
```

Is equivalent to:

```
SCREEN_SIZE =  800, 600
SCREEN_COLOR  = pygame.Color("white")
```

**EDIT:**

You're still getting a square because you're painting the circle *outside* the `Surface` that you blit on the screen.

This line is problem because `self.x` and `self.y` are outside the `self.surface`.

```
pygame.draw.circle(self.surface, pygame.Color("black"), (self.x, self.y), self.r)
```

Solution:

```
pygame.draw.circle(self.surface, pygame.Color("black"), 
                           (int(self.surface.get_width()/2),
                            int(self.surface.get_height()/2)), 
                           self.r)
```

Or IMHO better (but it really depends on how you implement other parts of game):

```
# ...
class Splatter(object):
    def __init__(self, r):
        self.r = int(r)
        self.surface = pygame.Surface((r*2, r*2))
        self.surface.fill(pygame.Color("red"))
        pygame.draw.circle(self.surface, pygame.Color("black"), 
                           (int(self.surface.get_width()/2),
                            int(self.surface.get_height()/2)), 
                           self.r)

    def display(self, x, y):
        SCREEN.blit(self.surface, (int(x), int(y)))


SCREEN.fill(SCREEN_COLOR)
s = Splatter(20)
s.display(SCREEN.get_width()/2, SCREEN.get_height()/2)
pygame.display.flip()
# ...
```

You don't need the coordinates when creating the `Splatter` you need them when you display it.

Comment: Can you explain how is it I'm painting black on black? Does self.surface = pygame.Surface((r*2, r*2)) have a black color by default?

Comment: @flashburn Yes, `Surface`s are black by default. Also just in case this isn't clear `pygame.Surface((r*2, r*2))` still creates a rectangle (i.e. it doesn't matter what you call your variables).

Comment: I've changed the code. You can take a look at above. However I'm still getting a square instead of a circle.

Comment: Thanks man. It worked. Another request if I may. Is it possible to make the surface, on which the circle is drawn, completely transparent?

Comment: @flashburn Maybe [set_alpha](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.set_alpha) but I haven't tested it and it may not be what you want. Look at [docs](http://www.pygame.org/docs/). If that won't help you ask another question - we're getting really out of topic here.